# Last boot time WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi

```
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -computerName $svr | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={($now - $($_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime))).days}}
```

This work perfect but my question is is there any way to get those computer names which are not went in the pipeline, I mean to say those computer which are not accessible or RCP error or Access denied.?

I would like to know if any server is shut down or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample doesn't show how you're inputting mulitple machine-names.. But an solution is somethign like this, using try-catch:

```
$pcs = Get-Content .\list-of-machines.txt
$now = Get-Date

$pcs | ForEach-Object {    
    $pc = $_

    try {
        Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $pc -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
                MachineName = $pc
                Uptime = ($now - ($_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime))).days
                Result = "SUCCESS"
            }
        }
    } catch {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            MachineName = $pc
            Result = $_.Exception.Message
        }
    } 
} |
#Export to CSV
Select MachineName, Uptime, Result | Export-Csv .\Uptime-results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code some if you create the object on the front end:

```
foreach ($srv in $serverlist)
{
  $result = New-Object psobject -Property @{csname=$srv;LastBootUpTime=$null}

  Try {
        $result.LastBootUpTime =
         Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $svr  -ErrorAction Stop |
          foreach {($now - $($_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime))).days}
      }

   Catch {$result.LastBootUpTime = $_.Exception.Message}

 $result
```

}